# Deploy ASP MVC in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I have existing silverlight app which works as IIS application. And i need to deploy ASP MVC app as a part of this (don't ask me why) in virtual directory, not like new IIS application. 
I use IIS 6.
I create new virtual directory in existing iis application and use path to ASP project folder as physical path of this virtual directory. But i get error

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file 
required to  service this request. Please review the specific error details 
below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to 
start monitoring changes to 'C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\MVCApp' because 
access is denied.

Source Error: 
[No relevant source lines]
```

Is it possible to deploy ASP MVC application in virtual directory?
How to do this right?

Comment: Have you hardcoded `'C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\MVCApp'` somewhere? or is the application actually on your **desktop**?

Comment: it's actually at my desctop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that should be possible. I'm guessing whatever service account your deployment process is running as doesn't have permission to write to C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\MVCApp.

To prove that out, you could modify permissions on that folder to allow 'Everyone' write access. If that works, figure out what account your process is running as, and grant that read/write/whatever, and remove the 'Everyone' access.

That should get your deployment situation fixed. I can't speak to how the two apps will run side by side. I'd need more info.

Comment: Yes. It resolved my problem. Thx. Now i have access to this folder through browser. But it works like explorer(i just can see files in project folder). But it's not working like web app.